# Importance of Aliyah in judaism

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, aliya-laaretz

I've heard a lot that making Aliyah to Israel is really good, that it's a mitzvah and even that it's an obligation if you can. But how important it is to make Aliyah? Could you give me references/quotes?

Comment: [http://www.yutorah.org/togo/5768/yomhaatzmaut/articles/Yom_HaAtzmaut_To-Go_-_5768_-_Rabbi_Kenneth_Brander.pdf](http://www.yutorah.org/togo/5768/yomhaatzmaut/articles/Yom_HaAtzmaut_To-Go_-_5768_-_Rabbi_Kenneth_Brander.pdf)

Comment: WHile I'm not voting to close, yet. I think you can clarify which aspects you seek in the aswers. The term "important" makes your question vague. Do you mean strictly from halachic viewpoint, political view, demographic / population view, or say, in light of the current "matzav" to support and unify with Israelis who are in danger?

Comment: related, possible duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11084/mitzvah-of-living-in-eretz-yisrael

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Moshe Feinstein ruled that there is no obligation to move to Israel nowadays, but if one does they fulfill a positive mitzvah of the Torah. 
See Igros Moshe, Even Ha'ezer (a), page 253, last paragraph of responsa 102.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in your source from Rav Moshe (where he said this)?

Comment: I put the source in at the end of the answer.  I hope it is clear. If not, tell me and I will try to be more clear. Sorry for the delay in editing it in.