# Why don't Jews return to Israel?

Tags: eretz-yisrael

Why are Jews still scattered around the world? Why do most live outside of Israel? Many are orthodox or have a very nostalgic religious view of belonging to that place. So what prevents them from settling in Israel? Is there anything in Jewish theology that explains this phenomenon? Some might argue that this is a service of the future messiah but in today's context what explains this majority outside of Israel?

Comment: related if not duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11071/what-justifications-are-there-for-not-moving-to-eretz-yisrael